# Android line drawing game (e.g. Flight Control) tutorial?

Tags: android, line-drawing

I'm looking for a tutorial that allows me to make a simple line tracing app, no other fancy stuff such as collision. If I can get an object to follow a line drawn on the screen at the end of this week that would be wonderful.

After getting familiar with android dev, creating a few apps (calculators, converters), I think I'm ready to step it up a bit with a game containing a main loop.

I think this is exactly what I'm looking for: http://www.rengelbert.com/tutorial.php?id=182

Here is the demo: http://www.rengelbert.com/swf/LineDrawing.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually quite vague and it would help if you actually supplied some code snippets, variables, formulas, to help us understand your scenario. I'm going to make the following assumptions to help me guide an answer:

- I have a line segment defined by (x1, y1) - (x2, y2)
- I want to make an animation of an object that follows the line segment
- The object needs to be orientated the correct direction
- Lets assume the object moves at a speed of 1 pixel per second

Okay, now we have established the parameters, we can provide some Java code:

```
// Define the line segment.
double x1 = /* ... insert value  here */;
double y1 = /* ... insert value  here */;;
double x2 = /* ... insert value  here */;;
double y2 = /* ... insert value  here */;;

// Determine both the direction and the length of the line segment.
double dx = x2 - x1;
double dy = y2 - y1;
double length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // length of the line segment
double orientation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

// Now for any time 't' between 0 and length, let's calculate the object position.
double x = x1 + t * dx / length;
double y = y1 + t * dy / length;
showObjectAt(x, y, orientation);
```

As to following a tutorial on building a game loop for your application, I highly recommend you follow the series on http://www.mybringback.com/ particularly Travis' Android tutorial on working with the SurfaceView object at http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3266/android-the-basics-28-introduction-to-the-surfaceview/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think I have the most trouble with starting the code. Thanks I see you've written some code for a straight line, but to jump from that to something like this: http://www.rengelbert.com/swf/LineDrawing.html (left click and drag your mouse on the plane), looks a little challenging and difficult. I'll check out the surfaceview tutorial in the meantime, thanks again.